# Does a restart in a Dockerfile make sense?

Tags: apache, docker, dockerfile

**Does a restart in a Dockerfile make sense?**

In my case I got a Dockerfile with apache httpd on it. In the file are some actions to configure the webserver. At the end of the file it says `RUN service apache2 restart`. And this seems odd to me.

I'm still getting used to Docker concepts. I conceptualize docker images as installation cd's and docker containers as installed machines.
The Dockerfile itself is then a set of instructions to follow before burning the CD image.
From that perspective it seems useless to restart apache just before burning the CD. Am I right with this conceptualisation?
And, or otherwise or, am I right with the statement that this file doesn't need a restart at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct - this doesn't make much sense. It will try and start a httpd, so might do some initial file setup.

You *might* be seeing an attempt to start HTTPD within the container, e.g. `CMD`/`ENTRYPOINT` - where it makes a little more sense, as `restart` means really "stop-and-start".

Stopping is redundant, but harmless, so this is actually a fairly common way of starting httpd if you're not sure if it's already running.

Comment: Thanks Sobrique. I think that this apache httpd (d!!) starts automatically. And as you suggest, it should use `CMD`/`ENTRYPOINT` to start the deamon, right?

Comment: I would normally suggest a 'run.sh' script myself, because then you can wrap up some pre startup commands.

Answer (score 0):

Although, you could use the `RUN` instruction for restart a service like `apache2`, due to the flexibility provided for creating images through a `Dockerfile`, its not recommended way. Refer [Dockerfile Best Practices and most common use cases](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices)

> RUN
>
> Probably the most common use-case for RUN is an application of
>   apt-get. When using apt-get ...
>
> CMD
>
> The CMD instruction should be used to run the software contained by
>   your image, along with any arguments. CMD should almost always be used
>   in the form of CMD [“executable”, “param1”, “param2”…]. Thus, if the
>   image is for a service (Apache, Rails, etc.), you would run something
>   like CMD ["apache2","-DFOREGROUND"]. Indeed, this form of the
>   instruction is recommended for any service-based image.

Therefore, using the `service restart` with the `CMD` instruction would be more appropriate.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. It was not the question whether to use run / cmd; it was my question if a restart in this scenario makes sense at all.

Comment: I understand, restart of service does not make sense in either instructions, though the dockerfile gives the flexibility. In most cases if you are running an daemon its recommended using the CMD Instruction.